# aggregate some values of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got a little problem with my SQL table:

[image]

I was minding if in SQL server is possible to populate the trasco_tot column with the total of the [importo a deb] values where id_testata is the same; 
output example

```
Importo a deb     id_testata      tot
     31               1           148
     117              1           148
     14               2            14
     …               …            …
     154              12          160
     6                12          160
```

I can manage the data with access too, and with the recordset and some if I could manage to obtain the trick, but I was wondering if there were a solution in SQL server too, because the execution of the query will be much faster than a recordset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily be accomplished with `sum` window function. Try this:

```
select [Importo a Deb], [trasco_id_testdata],
       sum([Importo a Deb]) over (partition by [trasco_id_testdata]) as [trasco_tot]
from my_table
```

You could also use it in `update` statement:

```
update t1 set t1.[trasco_tot] = t2.[trasco_tot] from my_table t1
join (select [trasco_id_testdata], sum([Importo a Deb]) over (partition by [trasco_id_testdata]) [trasco_tot] from my_table) t2
on t1.[trasco_id_testdata] = t2.[trasco_id_testdata]
```

Or simplier:

```
update t1 set t1.[trasco_tot] = t2.[trasco_tot] from my_table t1
join (select [trasco_id_testdata], sum([Importo a Deb]) [trasco_tot] from my_table group by [trasco_id_testdata]) t2
on t1.[trasco_id_testdata] = t2.[trasco_id_testdata]
```

Comment: i tried the select statement and i correctly display the results, but when i try to execute it through the update, i got the message error: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses". I also tried to put my conditions in the where clause and my order by with the same results: the select works fine, while the update returns the error

Comment: you got me there. Really thanks, i'm still quite the newbie here and i didn't think about a selfjoin

Comment: @Serphentelm Yes, you're right - self join is is one of the option, which must be used in `update` statement. That gives yet another possibility, which I also included in answer.